# Extracting Outlook Attachment from Saved Email

Tags: python-2.7

I have an analysis project that is requiring me to extract the 'current state' of a PDF that houses our report that is sent out 4 times daily.  I have the code written to scrape my PDF but I need to figure out how to extract the PDF from the email so I can step through it with my code.

I tried using the code below

```
import win32com.client
import os

location = r'C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive - companyinfo\Department Projects\TestEmails'

files = [f for f in os.listdir(location)]
print(files)

for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.msg'):
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(file)
        att = msg.Attachments
        for i in att:
            i.SaveAsFil`e(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\username\OneDrive - companyname\Department Projects\TestPDF', i.FileName))
```

The error it produces is:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, u'Microsoft Outlook', u"We can't open 'Stats Report.msg'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.\n\nTo check your permissions, right-click the file folder, then click Properties.", None, 0, -2147287038), None)
```

I am only currently testing with one saved test.msg file but I have over 1400 I need to parse through.  Maybe this isn't the best technique as I know VBA could do something similar within outlook, but I don't have much skills in the VBA region.

I have outlook 2016 installed on Windows 7 computer running python 2.7.  Is this error something easy to fix? Is there a better technique to take an attached PDF and save it to a folder so my other program can grab the necessary data?

Desired output: PDF Attachment is Extracted and Saved into a separate folder.

Thank you for your help and expertise,

Andy

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out the answer and how simple and stupid it was makes me unreasonably frustrated.....

My working directory was wrong even though I grabbed the file, the file name was the only item created.

I created a true_location variable that gave it the true full working directory and it worked like a charm.

```
true_location = location + '\\' + file
```

Enter that in the for loop under the if clause and it works like a charm.

Best,

Andy